# How to display selected multiple dropdown values in select2 jquery laravel8

Tags: jquery, laravel-8, jquery-select2-4, ui-select2

i have 3 tables dealer_master,distributor_master,dsdl_master. In dsdl_master table dealer specific distributor has been saved.

I have getting all the distributor list. using dsdl_master table i'm getting selected distributor_id against specific dealer.

In edit page i want display/show that selected distributor .

Below is my controller with strored procedure

```
public function addDistributor(){
        $dealer_id='DL-1';
        $data['all_dist'] = DB::select("CALL fetchDealerDetails()");
        $data['selected_dealer_distributor'] = DB::select("CALL specificIdDelaerDistributor('".$dealer_id."')");
        // return $data;
        return view('distributor.create',$data);
    }
```

Stored Procedure as follows :

```
specificIdDelaerDistributor - SELECT * from dsdl_master WHERE dl_id = dealer_id
fetchDistributorDetails - select * from master_distributor
```

My view file as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Multiple Select2</label>
    <select id="multiple" class="js-states form-control" multiple>
        @foreach ($all_dist as $item)
            <option value="{{$item->ds_id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>   
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Script as follow :

```
<script>
      $("#multiple").select2({
          placeholder: "Select Distributor",
          allowClear: true
      });
</script>
```

boostrap and js file as follows:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Select2 CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Select2 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

If anyone have idea then please let me know

Data get in below format:

```
{"all_dist":[{"ds_id":"DS-1","name":"distr1","email":"distr1@gmail.com"},{"ds_id":"DS-2","name":"distr2","email":"distr2@gmail.com"},{"ds_id":"DS-3","name":"distr3","email":"distr3@gmail.com"},{"ds_id":"DS-4","name":"distr4","email":"distr4@gmail.com"}],"selected_dealer_distributor":[{"id":1,"dl_id":"DL-1","ds_id":"DS-1"},{"id":2,"dl_id":"DL-1","ds_id":"DS-2"},{"id":3,"dl_id":"DL-1","ds_id":"DS-3"}]}
```